# On non-existence of two independent random experiments on a same probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question on Probability as follows:

"Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Then, on $\Omega$ we cannot construct two independent random experiments in which each experiment is that we select randomly an element $\omega$ from $\Omega$ with replacement".

In below, Michael Hardy gave an answer for the problem. It's very difficult to understand this answer. Can someone help me to explain the answer in detail.

Comment: This is obviously wrong. Sure about the text of the exercise?

Comment: I believe the proposition to be proved is correct.

Comment: @Hardy. Can you give me some explains on your comment?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: OK, the proposition is true in the case where $\Omega$ is finite, but I am not yet sure of the infinite case.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Note that you suggest ways of constructing probability spaces Omega with some given property while the exercise asks to prove that *every* probability space satisfies said property. (What you actually do in your answer, in its present form, is more unclear than what I said, but let us not focus on this point here.)

Comment: @Did : What my answer shows is that it's impossible when $\Omega$ is finite, except in the one completely trivial case.  It's true that I treat only one case; I'm leaving it as an exercise to generalize it.  Maybe I'll add something explicit on that.

Comment: @Did : Now I've added something at the end showing that the same is true over every finite probability space in which there is an element whose probability is strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In one trivial case, the thing can be done.  That is the case where one member of $\Omega$ has probability $1$ and all others have probability $0$.  Otherwise it is impossible when $\Omega$ is finite.

One can construct such "experiments" on a product space whose underlying set is the product $\Omega\times\Omega$ and the probability measure is a product measure.  One randomly chooses a point $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\Omega\times\Omega$, distributed according to the product measure, and then the projection functions
$$
(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto\omega_1
$$
and
$$
(\omega_1,\omega_2)\mapsto\omega_2
$$
are independent.

But the problem is to choose a single $\omega\in\Omega$, distributed according to $P$, and then find two functions
$$
\omega\mapsto\omega_1\in\Omega\text{ and } \omega\mapsto\omega_2\in\Omega
$$
that are independent.  Now if the space is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $P$ is the uniform distribution, then one can indeed construct independent random variables, for example
\begin{align}
& \omega\mapsto\text{even or odd, as the case may be}, \\
& \omega\mapsto\begin{cases}
\text{small} & \text{if }\omega\in\{1,2\}, \\
\text{medium} & \text{if }\omega\in\{3,4\}, \\
\text{large} & \text{if }\omega\in\{5,6\}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
But in this case the value of each random variable is not a member of $\Omega$.  You would need to find a way to roll the die once and map the outcome, just one number, to one of the $36$ pairs of numbers in the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ in such a way that the two components of the pair are independent.  Each pair would have probability $1/36$.  This is clearly impossible when $\Omega$ is finite.

The question is whether there is a mapping $\Omega\to\Omega\times\Omega$ for which the two projections are independent according to the measure $P$ on the domain.

In the case of the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ I'm not sure it can't be done by means of a Peano curve.

To show that the same is true of every finite probability space that assigns probability strictly between $0$ and $1$ to at least one point, consider the one $\omega_0\in\Omega$ with the smallest positive probability, and call that smallest positive probability $p$.  The map $\omega\mapsto(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ would have to take some element to the pair $(\omega_0,\omega_0)$, which should have probabilty $p^2$.  But there is no one element whose probability is $p^2$.

Mercio's comment below gives an example of one case in which such an experiment exists when $\Omega$ is infinite.

Comment: you can pick $\Omega = \{0;1\}^\Bbb N$ (infinitely many coin tosses) and take the mapping $(x_n) \mapsto (x_{2n}), (x_{2n+1})$

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the statement "The map $\omega \mapsto (\omega_1,\omega_2)$ would have to take some element to the pair $(\omega_0,\omega_0)$, which should have probability $p^2$" ?

Comment: @User3101 :  Just think of the problem of throwing a die.  There are six possible outcomes, each with the same probability, $1/6$.  If that choice were to determine _two_ elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ chosen independently, that would mean that some one of those would give you the pair $(5,3)$, and that would happen one time out of $36$.  But there is no outcome among $1,2,3,4,5,6$ that appears one time out of $36$. ${}\qquad{}$